# binary '[' : 'std::initializer_list<const char *>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

How do I access a value from this initializer declared using `auto` keyword?

```
auto arr = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
auto a = arr[0];
```

Give the following compile-error on VS:

> binary '[' : 'std::initializer_list' does not define
>   this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the interface of [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
auto arr = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
              "seven", "eight", "nine" };
auto a = *arr.begin();
```

(or, to be more practical, initialize a container or an array with your braced-init-list)

Comment: That's it. I'm not much used to C++'s way (since I do it much in "C's way") like `begin()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterators to traverse the initializer list. Function `begin()` returns a pointer to the first element in the initializer list.

```
int main() {

    auto arr = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
              "seven", "eight", "nine" };
    auto a = *arr.begin();
    auto b = *( arr.begin() + 1);

    cout << a << "," << b; // prints: one,two

    return 0;
}
```